# Broken button styling in Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

According to documentation, this is how you style a button with Tailwind:

```html
<button class="py-2 px-4 bg-green-500 text-white rounded-lg shadow-md hover:bg-green-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-400 focus:ring-opacity-75">
  Click me
</button>
```

This shouldn't require any special configuration.

But when I try this code in [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/mOHj54v9iv), the button doesn't even get rendered.

What gives?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me when I paste it into a new sandbox: 
https://play.tailwindcss.com/mOHj54v9iv

Comment: For me, your button was showing - https://ibb.co/5xXvMdT.

Comment: Strange. When I paste the code into a new sandbox, I get an unstyled button like this https://i.imgur.com/UWiOoko.png, and when I generate a share link and reload it, I get no button whatsoever: https://i.imgur.com/51urEXA.png

Comment: The little loading wheel in both of your images means Tailwind Play isn't loading fully for you, maybe something with your browser? Have you tried incognito mode/other browser?